# row size limit and list row size for a list or libray

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list

What is the difference between list row size and row size limit in software boundaries anyone can give one example for a list or library in a sharepoint site, we have multiple server farms.

Answer (score 1):

**Row Size Limit:** the limit of row size that is 8000 bytes.

> **Note:** Each list or library item can only occupy 8,000 bytes in total in the database. 300 bytes are reserved, leaving 7700 bytes for
>   end-user columns. For details on how much space each kind of field
>   consumes, This is the row size limit as boundary type that is Static limits that cannot be exceeded by design.

**List Row Size:** the current row size that is the sum of the current columns size.

---

**Example**

Consider you have a List item (row) with 2 columns as the following

- Single line of text (30 bytes as a column size limit),
- Number (14 bytes a column size limit)

> To check column limits check [Software boundaries and limits for
>   SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt493258%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Column)

So based on columns size, the **List Row Size** = 30 +14 = 44 bytes as `rows size`

In this case, you still can add additional [columns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Column) that its total size is less than or equal to the **Rows Size Limit** that `7700 bytes` per row.

**See also** [Comparing List and Library limits in SharePoint 2016 with SharePoint 2013 / 2010 / 2007](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/05/compare-sharepoint-2016-list-library-limits-with-sharepoint-2013-2010/)